# awk print lines where the values of any of 5 fields are different, ignoring missing data

Tags: awk

I'm trying to figure out if there are any pairwise differences in the values of 5 fields (fields 4-8) in my tabular file. Missing data are represented by the string "na". I'd like to print any lines with more than one value in these fields ignoring missing data (for instance, T and G in the first line of the example below), or more than two values if including "na".

Here are a few lines from the data file I'm working with:

```
2       1150    T       na      na      na      T       G
2       1151    C       na      na      na      T       C
2       1156    A       na      na      na      A       T
2       10742   C       T       na      T       na      na
2       10769   G       A       na      A       na      na
2       10781   T       G       na      G       na      na
2       58959   C       na      na      G       G       na
2       66907   G       na      na      A       G       na
2       66911   A       na      na      T       A       na
2       73087   C       C       na      C       C       T
2       92844   G       na      na      na      T       T
2       92846   T       na      na      na      T       G
2       99932   G       G       G       na      GT      na
```

The output I'm aiming for would be:

```
2       1150    T       na      na      na      T       G
2       1151    C       na      na      na      T       C
2       1156    A       na      na      na      A       T
2       66907   G       na      na      A       G       na
2       66911   A       na      na      T       A       na
2       73087   C       C       na      C       C       T
2       92846   T       na      na      na      T       G
2       99932   G       G       G       na      GT      na
```

This seems to be a bit beyond my skill level so I'd appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk for `delete array` and `length(array)`:

```
$ awk '{delete unq; for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) unq[$i]} length(unq)>2' file
2       1150    T       na      na      na      T       G
2       1151    C       na      na      na      T       C
2       1156    A       na      na      na      A       T
2       66907   G       na      na      A       G       na
2       66911   A       na      na      T       A       na
2       73087   C       C       na      C       C       T
2       92846   T       na      na      na      T       G
2       99932   G       G       G       na      GT      na
```

`delete array` has actually been part of POSIX since 2012 (see http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=544) and `length(array)` isn't only available in gawk, but also in other awks, so you could try the above on your awk and it might work even if it's not gawk.

Comment: brilliant idea for `length(unq) >2`!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, a version that doesn't rely on GNU-specific features:

```
awk '{ c=0; split("",a); for(i=4;i<=NF;++i) if(!a[$i]++) c++ } c>2' file
```

The variable `c` keeps a count of all unique entries in the fields from the 4th to the last. `!a[$i]++` identifies unique entries by only being true the first time it is evaluated for a given value `$i`. If more than two unique entries have been found, the record is printed. `split("", a)` achieves the effect of `delete a`, as splitting the empty string results in an array with no elements.

Comment: It took longer for me to deconstruct this one to figure out what exactly was happening with the array and it seems no less elegant than the first answer. Thanks again!